# Advanced Filter of unique values from column copies duplicate values

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy the unique values of a column from sourceTable to destTable by using this line of code:

```
sourceTable.DataBodyRange.Columns(myCol).AdvancedFilter _ 
  Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=destTable.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 1), _
  Unique:=True
```

This copies all the unique values, but it adds the first value of the sourceTable column twice.  A workaround could be to delete the first row of destTable, but I'd like to know why this happens.

Additionally, the name of the cell that the duplicated value is changed to something else by excel.  It depends on the table, but for example, the name of first cell change to "Extract" instead of "A28" (Appears as "Extract" in name manager).  Any explanation of this would be nice as well.

Comment: You need to include a header row when using AF, otherwise the first entry will be treated as such.

Comment: ^^ So possibly change both instances of `DataBodyRange` to `Range`.

Comment: Changing to range on either one throws the runtime error "The extract range has a missing or invalid field name".  I tried clearing both the databodyrange and the headerrowrange, but to no avail.

Comment: What are the headers for the source column and the destination column?

Comment: The value for both headers is "Service Rep", and the name for the source is "Y12", the name for the dest is "A31".  I don't see how the value or names should impact the copy

Comment: I think we need to see a data sample that illustrates the problem to be able to help. Preferably upload a file to some sharing site, and post a link here.  Or create a table as text, perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables),

Comment: Just got around to trying it on a different workbook and it worked.  However, the name for the first cell is changed to "Extract" again, not sure why